# Converting COM DLL to .NET DLL is Possible?

Tags: .net, com

I have a WIN32 COM DLL.
And I want to Convert .NET DLL.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: what languague is wrriten in?

Comment: Do you mean it needs to be callable from a dotNet object?  That's easy using COM Interop.

Comment: @Zippit: unless it uses extra success codes for important information (i.e. you can't lose the information), in which case more work is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not impossible.